# KALDI after training

Tags: speech-recognition, transfer-learning, kaldi

I've been doing some KALDI learning these days and I follow the tutorial and I complete some examples like yesno, voxforge, ynstadial, and a custom digits ASR.

But after all of the above completed I only got something like WER 5% and some log.

How can I use them like a microphone or something?

Also, I am trying to do some incremental learning or transfer training on the KALDI dummy tutorial's example but I don't know how to start. Can anyone help me with what to learn or what to do?

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Kaldi allows online and offline decoding.
[https://kaldi-asr.org/doc/online_decoding.html][1]

Demo is available in kaldi/egs/vox directory. See gst and online demo folders
. [https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/master/egs/voxforge][2]

Details to follow in the comments

Comment: A good way to build up basics before going deep into Kaldi is
1. Learn speech processing fundamentals on [www.speech.zone][3]
2. Learn Linux Hands on. Check [cbtnuggets.com][4]
3. Learn Natural Language Processing and basics of Data science and ML Ops. Check Andrew NG courses on [deeplearning.ai][5]


  [1]: https://kaldi-asr.org/doc/online_decoding.html
  [2]: https://github.com/kaldi-asr/kaldi/tree/master/egs/voxforge
  [3]: https://www.speech.zone
  [4]: https://cbtnuggets.com
  [5]: https://deeplearning.ai

Comment: Some beginner kaldi help is available on 
https://jrmeyer.github.io/
https://chrisearch.wordpress.com/2017/03/11/speech-recognition-using-kaldi-extending-and-using-the-aspire-model/#
https://www.assemblyai.com/blog/kaldi-speech-recognition-for-beginners-a-simple-tutorial/
https://kunal-dhawan.weebly.com/asr-system-for-hindi-language-from-scratch.html

Learn how to integrate your own Language Model built on kaldi with vosk for online and offline Speech to text on https://medium.com/@andimid/offline-foreign-speech-recognition-32d8d63de2dc